# How can I use gspread in Python3 to print the value of an xpath in the left cell next to a corresponding URL?

Tags: python-3.x, gspread

My intent is to scrape the value of an xpath from a range of URLs, found in the fourth column of a Google Sheet, and to print that value in the cell to the left of the URL.

I have the below so far, but when I run this, it prints the last value of the adGroupStatus list for all URLs, rather than the correct value for each corresponding URL.

Can anyone offer a solution?

```py
import requests
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from lxml import html

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sh = client.open('example_sheet_name')
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)

# the column (4th) with our URLs
url_list = worksheet.col_values(4)
# where we want our xpath values to print to
cell_list = worksheet.range('C1:C5')

def grab_xpathtext(urls, cell_range):
    # do the below for each url in the spreadsheet column 4:
    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url)
        tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
        adGroupStatus = tree.xpath('//*[@id="m_count"]/text()')
                # below prints each value to the cmd line on a new line as expected
        print(adGroupStatus[0])
    for cell in cell_range:
        # below prints the last value instead of each corresponding value
        cell.value = adGroupStatus[0]
    worksheet.update_cells(cell_range)

grab_xpathtext(url_list, cell_list)
```

I expect the output to resemble the this:

| location 1 | description | **1** | url 1 |

| location 2 | description | **2** | url 2 |

| location 3 | description | **3** | url 3 |

| location 4 | description | **4** | url 4 |

| location 5 | description | **5** | url 5 |

... but instead I get this:

| location 1 | description | **5** | url 1 |

| location 2 | description | **5** | url 2 |

| location 3 | description | **5** | url 3 |

| location 4 | description | **5** | url 4 |

| location 5 | description | **5** | url 5 |

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this in another question:
[Python/gspread - how can I update multiple cells with DIFFERENT VALUES at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675258/python-gspread-how-can-i-update-multiple-cells-with-different-values-at-once?rq=1)

Implemented as:

```py
url_list = worksheet.col_values(4)
cell_list = worksheet.range('C1:C5')

def grab_xpathtext(urls, cell_range):
        statuses = []
        for url in urls:
            r = requests.get(url)
            tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
            adGroupStatus = tree.xpath('//*[@id="m_count"]/text()')
            statuses.append(adGroupStatus[0])
        print(statuses)
        for cell in cell_range:
            for i, val in enumerate(statuses):
                cell_range[i].value = val
        worksheet.update_cells(cell_range)

grab_xpathtext(url_list, cell_list)
```