# gspread worksheet.update error - Worksheet has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-colaboratory, gspread

I am trying to write a dataframe to an open Google Sheet in Google Colab, but am getting the error:

AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'update'

I documented and tested the parts up to the error.

```
# General Imports
# Example at https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

#Import the library, authenticate, and create the interface to Sheets.
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Load the DataFrame
dataframe = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2' ,'3'], ['Mary', 'Mai', 'Kat']]
print(dataframe)

# Open the Google Sheet
# This assumes that you have  worksheet called "RS Output" with sheet "Data" on your Google Drive,

gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

my_workbook = 'RS Output'
my_sheet = "Data"

worksheet = gc.open(my_workbook).worksheet(my_sheet)

list_of_lists = worksheet.get_all_values()
print(list_of_lists)

# update the Google Sheet with the values from the Dataframe
# per gspread documentation at 
# https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html

worksheet.update([dataframe.columns.values.tolist()] + worksheet.values.tolist())
```

This is the output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['Mary', 'Mai', 'Kat']]
[['Testing'], ['This']]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-e085af26b2ed> in <module>()
     21 # https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html
     22 
---> 23 worksheet.update([dataframe.columns.values.tolist()] + worksheet.values.tolist())

AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'update'
```

I can't seem to find a clear example of how to write the dataframe to a Google Sheet.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between `dataframe = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2' ,'3'], ['Mary', 'Mai', 'Kat']]` and `dataframe.columns.values.tolist()`, and also, I cannot understand about the relationship between `worksheet = gc.open(my_workbook).worksheet(my_sheet)` and `worksheet.values.tolist()`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue, this is my first time using colab.research.google.com notebook.
it turned out the default gspread module was version 3.0

**!pip install --upgrade gspread**!

Updated it to version 3.7 and fixed the missing .update() problem.

```
Found existing installation: gspread 3.0.1
    Uninstalling gspread-3.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled gspread-3.0.1
Successfully installed gspread-3.7.0
```

Big thanks to: Shashank Rautela

Answer (score 1):

`AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'update'` means that the variable `worksheet` has no `update` attribute in it, you can verify that by adding `print(dir(worksheet))` in your code.

If the variable has update attribute, it should print something like this:

[image]

**Also, I tried to replicate your code and found some issues:**

1. `dataframe = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2' ,'3'], ['Mary', 'Mai', 'Kat']]` is already a list. `dataframe.columns.values.tolist()` will give you error since the variable `dataframe` is a list and has no attribute columns. Using only the variable `dataframe` in the update method is enough since it is already a list of list. Here is an example of a dataframe: `{'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}`.
2. Incorrect `worksheet.update()` usage. According to this [document](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#updating-cells), the parameter of `update()` are `range` and `values` (list of list if the range contains multiple cells). The parameter of your `update()` method should look like this: `worksheet.update("Range", data in form of list of list)`.

Here is an example on how to use the `update()` method:

**Using List:**

Code:

```
data = [["It" , "works!"]]
worksheet.update("A1:B1", data)
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

**Using panda's dataframe.**

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Age': [20, 19, 23]})
values = df.columns.values.tolist()
sh.update("A1:B1", [values])
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Based on how you used the `update()` method, you want to insert the column names
above the current data of worksheet. Instead of using update, you can use `insert_rows()`

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Age': [20, 19, 23]})
values = df.columns.values.tolist()
worksheet.insert_rows([values], row=1, value_input_option='RAW')
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

### References:

- [insert_rows](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=insert_row#gspread.models.Worksheet.insert_rows)
- [update](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=insert_row#gspread.models.Worksheet.update)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on a Jupyter notebook running on a server (ubuntu 18.04) while it works fine using Pycharm on my local machine (ubuntu 20.04) instead.

Meanwhile, here's how I push my pandas dataframe to a google spreadsheet:

```
import string    

# create a spreadsheet range that matches the size of the df (including 1 row for the column names). It looks like that: 'A1:AA3'
letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
col_names_spreadsheet = letters+list(np.array([[X+x for x in letters] for X in letters]).flat)
range_for_df = col_names_spreadsheet[0]+"1"+":"+col_names_spreadsheet[df.shape[1]-1]+str(df.shape[0]+1)

# retrieve the matching cells
cell_list = worksheet.range(range_for_df)

# flatten the df, add the column names at the beginning
cell_values = list(df.columns)+list(df.values.flat)

# set the value of each cell
for i, val in enumerate(cell_values):  #gives us a tuple of an index and value
    cell_list[i].value = val    #use the index on cell_list and the val from cell_values

# update the cells in bulk
worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```

if the df has dates it may return this error

> Object of type date is not JSON serializable

In this case I use this

```
# turn all datetime columns into strings
import datetime   
dt_cols = list(df.columns[[type(df[col].iloc[0]) is datetime.date for col in df.columns]])
for c in dt_cols:
    df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: x.isoformat())
```

credit to this guy for the trick: [Python/gspread - how can I update multiple cells with DIFFERENT VALUES at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675258/python-gspread-how-can-i-update-multiple-cells-with-different-values-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

**!pip install --upgrade gspread**

upgrade the gspread lib with above command.

you will be able to call  the update method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting any kind of **Attribute Error** *( assuming that you have used correct syntax and correct attributes for gspread )*
Then that is because you are using gspread's old version 3.0.1, if you haven't used gspread before in google colab then this is the standard version that comes pre-installed. Just do

---

**!pip install --upgrade gspread**

---

At the time of writing this gspread gets upgraded to version 3.7.1 with above command.

---

***Happy Coding!***